# What Ethereum blockchain explorers exist?

Tags: blockchain, contract-debugging, explorers

What blockchain explorers exist and

1. What special features do they have?
2. Are they open-source?
3. How reliable are they (approximate uptime in %)?
4. Is there a testnet version?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### **Hosted Main Chain Explorers:**

### https://ethtools.com/mainnet/chain

Can explore:

1. Contract Addresses
2. Non Contract Addresses
3. Transactions (and their internal steps)
4. Blocks
5. Contract Code

### https://www.etherchain.org

Can explore:

1. Contract Addresses
2. Non Contract Addresses
3. Transactions
4. Blocks
5. Contract Code

### https://live.ether.camp

Can explore:

1. Contract Addresses
2. Non Contract Addresses
3. Transactions
4. Blocks
5. Contract Code
6. Contract Storage (appears to the be only service to do so)
7. VM execution trace

### http://etherscan.io

Can explore:

1. Contract Addresses
2. Non Contract Addresses
3. Transactions
4. Blocks
5. Contract Code

### Hosted Testnet (Ropsten) Explorers:

- http://testnet.etherscan.io
- <s>https://ethtools.com/ropsten/chain</s> offline (2010/01/26)
- https://blockexplorer.one/eth/ropsten
- https://teth.bitaps.com/

### Hosted Testnet (Rinkeby) Explorers:

- https://rinkeby.etherscan.io

*PoA testnet started by the Ethereum team,
uses Clique PoA consensus protocol,
supported by geth only*

### Hosted Testnet (Kovan) Explorers:

- https://kovan.etherscan.io

*PoA testnet started by the Parity team,
supported by parity only*

### Open source projects:

- https://github.com/gobitfly/etherchain-light
- https://github.com/etherparty/explorer
- https://github.com/maran/ethereum-blockchain-explorer
- https://github.com/blk-io/epirus-free
- https://github.com/ConsenSys/cakeshop

### Outdated / defunct explorers:

- https://etherapps.info
- http://ether.fund/explorer

Comment: This anser is a [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740), this means that *you* can edit it to add missing blockchain explorers, update their status, etc

Comment: http://testnet.etherscan.io is (well, was) a Ropsten explorer.

Comment: Looks like https://ethtools.com/mainnet/chain/ is also defunct