# How can I check which network I'm working on?

Tags: clients, nodes, private-blockchain, network, cpp-ethereum

When I start `eth` I get the following header:

```
$ eth
(++)Ethereum
Beware. You're entering the Frontier!
[...]
```

I think i followed the instructions for working on a private network (because i just want to check out the technology) but how can i check if I'm working on the real network?

Answer (score 4):

By default, all Ethereum clients use the main "Frontier" network. If you haven't manually changed the genesis block or network ID, you're good to go.

If you want to be really sure you're on the right network, enter the console, using the command `eth console`, and type `var num = web3.eth.blockNumber` to get the latest block number. Then enter `web3.eth.getBlock(num).hash`. Go to a [block explorer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-ethereum-blockchain-explorers-exist), enter the block number, and make sure the hashes match up.

Comment: Maybe a brief explanation of "entering the console" with eth would also help.  Typo also "vat" (which I'd have edited directly but it may as well be done if you might do any other edits).