# Is there an easy, human centric way of viewing local Ethereum blockchain data?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, tools

[Etherchain](https://www.etherchain.org/) and [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/) provide information about the Ethereum blockchain.

What tools exist that will allow me to extract similar data from my local Ethereum (.ldb) files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, there are only 2 open source Ethereum blockchain explorers and both of them are a bit outdated it seems.

https://github.com/etherparty/explorer

https://github.com/maran/ethereum-blockchain-explorer

Those are the only open source tools available to extract your Ethereum ldb files at the moment.

[Check this StackExchange Answer for an up to date list of open source Ethereum Explorers.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/453/299)

Comment: I was actually looking for something that would operate on my local .ldb files, and not go through the web3 API, something that could be used on a private testnet.

Comment: Web3 APIs work on local test nets in exactly the same way as they do on the frontier network, silly me!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there are libraries like

1. [A lightweight ethereum block explorer](https://github.com/etherparty/explorer)

And for Bitcoin.

2. [An open source block explorer](https://github.com/iquidus/explorer)
3. [bitcoin-blockexplorer](https://github.com/bitcoin-blockexplorer/)