# Can I monitor contract's activity on any explorer?

Tags: blockchain, explorers, monitoring

Is there any way I can use a blockchain explorer or similar tool to find out how much activity there is on addresses for specific ethereum based services (Digix, Augur etc. pp.)?

Comment: WHAT IF A SMART CONTRACT / TOKEN IS NOT VISIBLE ON THE ETH EXPLORER ? A coin for example - written as a smart contract on the eth blockchain. If its not visible, is it a real decentralize coin ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can if you know the address. Just use any of the blockexplorers such as :

Etherscan.io, Etherchain.org or Live.ether.camp. You can see past transactions and the internal contract invocations. This gives you a good indication of "activity".

For more information on block explorers see [What Ethereum blockchain explorers exist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-ethereum-blockchain-explorers-exist?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Using blockchain explorers for quickly checking transaction or a specific smart contract activity is ok. But it gets tricky when you want to do real monitoring on the long run as :

1 - you don't have any control on what is scanned or what information

2 - the service is not local, so you are at risk any moment the service is 
    not available

3 - Since these explorers take the task of monitoring and reporting 
    activity about the 
    whole blockchain you will end up with some restrictions etherscan, for 
    the example doesn't process requests that return more than 10,000 
    transactions.

The solution is to create a local tool that you can run on your system or server that will monitor specific addresses you specify and return the whole activity they conduct.

Checkout 
https://github.com/Neufund/smart-contract-watch 
it's open source so you can anything you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Bitquery](http://bitquery.io/) gives you APIs and explorers to do real-time and detailed monitoring. The [builder](https://ide.bitquery.io/) is easy to use, you can just click select to add data.

For example:

- You can track [dex trades](https://docs.bitquery.io/v1/docs/Examples/dexTrades/dex-trading-data-api/#trades-for-a-specific-time-on-ethereum)
- [Transactions](https://docs.bitquery.io/v1/docs/Examples/Transactions/transaction-api/#ethereum-transaction-api)
- [Balance History for an Address](https://docs.bitquery.io/v1/docs/Examples/address/Blockchain-Address-API-Examples/#balance-history-of-an-address) and so on...
  Start with the Explorer
  [image]

Complete docs -> https://docs.bitquery.io/v1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a number of blockchain explorers to see the transactions coming to/from a given Ethereum address.

To do this through [EthTools.com](https://ethtools.com) you can simply enter the address in the search bar displayed on the right hand side of the header.

[image: EthTools.com header]

This will take you to a screen similar to the below from which you can deep dive into the details of specific transactions.

[image]

Disclaimer: My company built EthTools.com

Answer (score 0):

At QuickBlocks, we're building a fully client-side decentralize explorer. All the solutions mentioned above are centralized, and there, in our opinion, less applicable.