# what types of graph data are produced by the ethereum network?

Tags: network, data-feeds, graphs

I'm curious, what sort of node-link graph data is produced by the Ethereum network?  I imagine there there is a graph of all transactions, and a higher level graph of miners and the blocks they mined.  Are there similar emergent network datasets from other activities on the Ethereum network?

I build data visualizations, and would really like to create a force-layout network vis from some Ethereum data.

This [bitcoin network vis](http://dailyblockchain.github.io/) or this [citation network vis](http://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/8a173cfcb9171627c7f1) are examples of the sort of thing I'd like to create for Ethereum.

Comment: This question has a good chunk of your question answered, I suspect:   http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-ethereum-blockchain-explorers-exist