# ETH deposit to mist wallet, but balance not showing

Tags: mist, ether, synchronization

I made an ETH deposit to my Mist wallet, but the wallet does not show any balance after 100 confirmations. The wallet is new and blockchain is still syncing.

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: I'd guess that your transaction wouldn't show up until you've finished syncing the blockchain, or at least you've synced up to the block which contains the transaction.

Comment: alternatively you can check it it went well on a blockchain explorer, see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/404/54 for sone links