# Ethereum Private chain Explorers

Tags: private-blockchain, explorers

I have created a private blockchain by initializing a new Genesis block. Created few accounts and have now substantial amount of Ethers as well. I am able to deploy and execute my contracts on this blockchain with the help of truffle. Using Mist am able to view the account balances. But I am not able to view the deployed contract via Mist under Contracts menu. Secondly not able to see any of the transactions performed using my Dapp. Using my Dapp I can get the details about the transactions performed and the latest state.

So what I am looking for a good Ethereum explorer, which I could use for my private blockchain to view all the details.

Thus request you to please suggest some ethereum explorers which I could run locally. It should attach to my Geth instance. I could query all the details about the transactions performed using my Dapp on this private blockchain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an updated list from this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-ethereum-blockchain-explorers-exist/453#453):

> ### **Hosted Main Chain Explorers:**
>
> https://www.etherchain.org
>   ----------------------------- Can explore:
>
> 1. Contract Addresses
> 2. Non Contract Addresses
> 3. Transactions
> 4. Blocks
> 5. Contract Code
>
> https://live.ether.camp
>   -------------------------- Can explore:
>
> 1. Contract Addresses
> 2. Non Contract Addresses
> 3. Transactions
> 4. Blocks
> 5. Contract Code
> 6. Contract Storage (appears to the be only service to do so)
> 7. VM execution trace
>
> http://etherscan.io
>   ---------------------- Can explore:
>
> 1. Contract Addresses
> 2. Non Contract Addresses
> 3. Transactions
> 4. Blocks
> 5. Contract Code
>
> ### Hosted Testnet (Morden) Explorers:
>
> - https://morden.ether.camp
> - http://testnet.etherscan.io
>
> ### Open source projects:
>
> - https://github.com/gobitfly/etherchain-light
> - https://github.com/etherparty/explorer
> - https://github.com/maran/ethereum-blockchain-explorer
>
> ### Outdated / defunct explorers:
>
> - https://etherapps.info
> - http://ether.fund/explorer

Comment: Thanks for sharing the same! Believe based on my requirement the ones listed under Open source projects heading are the ones which will be useful.

Comment: there is also https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache

Answer (score 2):

I came across **ETHExplorer V2** Ethereum explorer.

> https://github.com/carsenk/explorer

On performing the basic installation steps I was able to run it on http://localhost:8000

> **Installation steps**
>   download the build
>   Using command prompt go to the root of the package
>   npm install
>   npm start
>   In case you face bower installation issue run "npm install -g bower
>   In case you face http-server installation issue run "npm install -g http-server

Using it I am able to traverse on my private blockchain showing all the transactions, blocks and account details.

Still would love to have come across more such browsers in case you feel those are better to this one and can work on private blockchains

Comment: I downloaded it but it shows difficulty in Terahashes, small difficulty will display as 0.0 TH/s , not a big help for private networks