# Monitor transactions on private chain

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ganache

I have a consortium chain (I have access to all machines where the nodes are running, but can't stop or restart them), and want to monitor what's happening on a high level. Similar to what ganache does:
[image]

Does geth offer something like this? 
(I know I can subscribe to events from web3.js and the likes, this is about any existing solutions available)

Comment: This link (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13667/ethereum-private-chain-explorers) and the dupe might help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Could you describe some use cases, what kind of events you want to monitor and what also you want to do with your nodes?

Comment: Just added a picture of how it looks in ganache-cli. I actually started writing some script myself to do this, but it's a bit hacky and I can't imagine nobody else has that some requirement

Answer (score 1):

Try running your `geth` nodes with `--verbosity debug` or `--verbosity detail`.

Comment: just clarified in my question - the nodes are running and I can get on the machines (and `geth attach`), but can't do anything with them

Comment: @Alex If you have console access you can try to increment the verbosity level [debug.verbosity](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_verbosity).