# Is there a list of Ethereum Classic block explorers?

Tags: ethereum-classic, explorers

Most Ethereum block explorers are only for Ethereum, but not Classic. Is there a list of Ethereum Classic explorers?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-ethereum-blockchain-explorers-exist

Comment: Options here would be to add ETC explorers to the above previous answer, or create a new community wiki answer here. I'll add some as an answer with a view to them being moved to the above if people decide that's best.

Comment: Community wiki questions don't accrue rep and have a lower full editing reputation threshold. Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion. This affects the question and all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of Ethereum Classic Blockchain Explorer

http://gastracker.io

http://etherhub.io

http://blockscout.com

http://0xeth.com

Answer (score 3):

**Currently online (as of 26th April 2017):**

- http://gastracker.io/
- https://etcplanet.org/

**Currently unreachable:**

- https://etherx.com/ (as of 26th April 2017)
- https://etherhub.io/ (as of 21st Jan 2018)
- https://etcchain.com/explorer (as of 21st Jan 2018)

Answer (score 0):

These are my favorites for exploring Ethereum blocks:

- etherscan.io
- ethplorer.io
- c-hound.ai (explorer + nice visual
  analytics!)

Answer (score 0):

New explorer we created for Ethereum Classic: https://explorer.bitquery.io/ethclassic