# Can someone please send me some test ether....I want to do some research

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

My ether address is 0xf63F46629bA18F50E93c10F249b04662c60788cd

You can use testnet to do the testing. Use the testnet faucet to get the Ether in testnet. Link is the following http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001

I tried many other faucet nothing worked

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  This is a Question & Answer rather than a support site.  This may also help https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-ethereum-blockchain-explorers-exist

Answer (score 3):

You can use testnet to do the testing. Use the testnet faucet to get the Ether in testnet. Link is the following http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001

Answer (score 2):

Use this faucet to get ether in your account -

http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

To get test ether, you should be connected to testnet and address used on faucet should be of one of the accounts on testnet.

Comment: it doesn't work !!