# Q&A: How to get all tokens assigned to a user?

Tags: tokens, ethereum-classic

**This part of own Q&A serial of posts which shares knowledge gained during work on one project**

I was looking for a way to get all tokens which belongs to a user. One more constrains is project is going to be deployed on the private chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually **etherscan** is used for this. **Etherscan** is not available for deployment on private chains, but it seems its core functions could be implemented with a reasonable amount of investments.

Some open sources alternatives are mentioned [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-ethereum-blockchain-explorers-exist/453#453).